# jQuery Validation Plugin - 'Required' rule behaving strangely

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, required

I'm using this [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) ([jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate)) in combination with Bootstrap, and I already made 5 forms with it & with a lot of pain.

I now have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IsaiahvH/638fu/2/), but my password field is behaving strangely...
As you can see, I set the `required` rule for the password, as for all. If I delete all bullets in my browser and move on to the next field, it is left untouched, if already marked correct, it remains correct, if not marked at all, remains unmarked. *It isn't marked incorrect, and the error message does not show up!*

I can only get my `required` rule error message to show up by first producing the `minlength` error on the password field, and *then* removing all characters, **or** by clicking the submit button (only available if all fields aren't in an error state).

After a lot of checking, I found the `onfocusout` option. This can be either `true` or `false`, with the default set to `true` As the website states,

> [It] Validate[s] elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid.

This would surely be the cause, I thought. But after a lot of googling, it turned out no one else had that problem (or at least, due to the `onfocusout` rule). One post did mention that "the `required` rule is an exception" (to the `onfocusout` rule?).

---

***Bottom line***: **I cannot get my `required` rule error to work**, with the exception when submitting or first producing the `minlength` error message. *Then*, it does show up.
***Conclusion***: The error can be produced, but not on `blur`.
***Question***: How to fix this?

---

My password input field

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="passw" name="passw" value="nochange" maxlength="20" required="required" placeholder="123456789" />
```

My password rules

```
passw: {
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 20
},
```

---

I added `console.log` messages upon when the error should've been placed - not even called. I validated my code and HTML, triple-checked everything, but I still can't find the bug...

Comment: This is happening because you are specifying a value before the rules even run, if you take out all the pre-determined value the checks work correctly....  http://jsfiddle.net/638fu/5/

Comment: @jeremy I see... However, I do need those pre-defined values. I just tried it with [setting those values through jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/IsaiahvH/638fu/7/), same problem. But it does get me closer, though it's not quite ideal.

Comment: You're right... you might have to set values and refocus to get this to work there might be a better solution that is not so "hacky"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quoting OP:**

> "I cannot get my required rule error to work, with the exception when submitting or first producing the minlength error message. Then, it does show up.  ....  I validated my code and HTML, triple-checked everything, but I still can't find the bug"

This is not a bug.  This is called "Lazy" validation and it's the default behavior.

[Documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/#link-a-few-things-to-look-out-for-when-playing-around-with-the-demo):

> *"Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages – they won't get bugged before having the chance to actually enter a correct value  ...  it is designed for an unobtrusive user experience, annoying the user as little as possible with unnecessary error messages"*

**Quoting OP:**

> "After a lot of checking, I found the `onfocusout` option. This can be either `true` or `false`, with the default set to true As the website states"

Not quite.  `onfocusout` is *active* by default; you cannot set it to `true` without breaking the plugin. You can only set it to `false` (to disable it) OR you can over-ride it with your own function.

[Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

> *"Set to a Function to decide for yourself when to run validation.  **A boolean `true` is not a valid value**."*

Modify the `onfocusout` callback option for more "Eager" validation, so that all validation triggers immediately upon leaving the field.

```
$('#yourform').validate({
    // your rules & options,
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
        this.element(element);  // eager validation
    }
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/p4K7S/](http://jsfiddle.net/p4K7S/)**

For a more complete "Eager" validation experience, do the same for the `onkeyup` callback function and validation will commence as soon as typing starts inside a field.

```
$('#yourform').validate({
    // your rules & options,
    onfocusout: function (element, event) {
        this.element(element);  // eager validation
    },
    onkeyup: function (element, event) {
        this.element(element);  // eager validation
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2: [jsfiddle.net/em0uspk3/](http://jsfiddle.net/em0uspk3/)**

Why would you still need `onfocusout` when using `onkeyup`?  Because there are no keyup events during user interactions with radio, checkbox, and select elements.

Comment: Some explanation about why this is the default behavior: *"...it is designed for an unobtrusive user experience, annoying the user as little as possible with unnecessary error messages"* (from the documentation). Maybe the OP would consider *not* validating those fields on `blur` with this in mind./

Comment: Thank-you @AndrewWhitaker for the reminder.  I added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, your idea works! I knew you couldn't set `onfocusout` to true, my bad, I merely meant it was already activated upon default. Also I understand that this behaviour isn't a bug, but I still needed to warn the user immediately due to the circumstances (you may not leave the field empty).

Comment: Uhm, what does `this.element(element);` do?

Comment: @Isaiah, it's [the `validator.element()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/), which will validate the element passed into it.  In this case, `this.element()` represents `validator.element()`, and the `element` keyword passed into it represents the field being validated.